# browser loading aws load balancer says connection is not private

Tags: amazon-web-services, ssl, load-balancing

Hi I was able to use AWS' canned SSL cert on an AWS load balancer that listens for incoming https traffic on 443 and returns http on 80 (was not able to return https over 443 their documentation refers to nonexistent buttons)

when i go to https://example.com my site loads fine and shows the https security green tag by the url.

however, when i go to my load balancer's address, which looks like

```
https://load-balancer-xxxxxx.us-east-1.elb.amazonaws.com/index.html
```

I see a webpage that says

```
Your connection is not private

Attackers might be trying to steal your information from load-balancer-xxxxxx.us-east-1.elb.amazonaws.com (for example, passwords, messages, or credit cards). NET::ERR_CERT_COMMON_NAME_INVALID
```

i am wondering if this means my ssl and https communication over https://example.com is not safe ? or what this error really means in terms of what i should be concerned about

is the error due to the fact that the certified url for my site does not contain the domain *.amazonaws.com ?

if so should i consider making my ssl certificate for both my domain.com and *.amazonaws.com ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

your communication is safe if you use https://yoursite.example.com. If you go to the *.amazonaws.com however, then your browser is not able to make sure that this is your real website, because your certificate does not cover this domain.

So to make it short: just use the example.com address (and not the other one) and this is all safe